# How do I add or subtract values read from access inside the vba code?

Tags: excel, vba, ms-access

I am reading in values from an access database and copying them to specific places on an excel sheet.
Some of the values from access needs to be added with another value from access, before it is copied to the excel sheet.
How do I change my code to do addition?

F.eks how do I add the value in the variable called "referansetrafikk" with another variable "nyskapt overfoert" before it gets pasted into the specific location on the excel sheet?

```
Sub HentData()

DBFullName = "C:\saga_effekt_Nidaros_2017_tiltak.mdb"
Application.ScreenUpdating = False
Set TargetRange = Sheets("1.3 Persontransportmodell").Range("A1")

Set cn = CreateObject("ADODB.Connection")
cn.Open "DRIVER={Microsoft Access Driver (*.mdb, *.accdb)};DBQ=C:\saga_effekt_Tiltak.mdb;"

Set rs = CreateObject("ADODB.Recordset")

rs.Open "SELECT [VERDI] FROM [saga_trafikantnytte] WHERE [MODE] = 'tog' AND [VARIABEL] = 'referansetrafikk'", cn, , , adCmdText
TargetRange.Offset(12, 4).CopyFromRecordset rs:Application.ScreenUpdating = True: On Error Resume Next: rs.Close: On Error GoTo 0

rs.Open "SELECT [VERDI] FROM [saga_trafikantnytte] WHERE [MODE] = 'tog' AND [VARIABEL] = 'nyskapt_overfoert'", cn, , , adCmdText
**strong text**TargetRange.Offset(13, 4).CopyFromRecordset rs: Application.ScreenUpdating = True: On Error Resume Next: rs.Close: On Error GoTo 0
```

Comment: for example declare a number variable `Long`or `Double` (depending on your needs) and make that variable the sum of your values

Comment: I have tried it, the problem is that when i write f.eks. new variable test=rs.Open "SELECT [VERDI] FROM [saga_trafikantnytte] WHERE [MODE] = 'tog' AND [VARIABEL] = 'nyskapt_overfoert'", cn, , , adCmdText I get "Compile error"

Answer (score 0):

Just use basic arithmatic in your SQL clause:

```
rs.Open "SELECT [VERDI], referansetrafikk + [nyskapt overfoert] As MyAddedVariable  FROM [saga_trafikantnytte] WHERE [MODE] = 'tog' AND [VARIABEL] = 'referansetrafikk'", cn, , , adCmdText
```

Of course, you could also perform any calculation after copying the recordset. Doing calculations with the recordset itself is bound to be slow and complicated.

Comment: When I try this, I only get the sum of the strings "referansetrafikk + [nyskapt overfoert] " not the values themselves

Comment: Then you should store values as values, and not as strings... You can use `Val` to convert them, but really should adjust the storage instead.

Comment: I really suck at vba coding, but as far as I understand I have declared both cn and rs as objects. When I then try to run the code as you said, I get an error "to few parameters, 2 expected) why does not it understand that I ask for the sum of 2, is it because one of them misses []?

Comment: I can't tell what you're doing wrong by just that comment. Obviously, if a name contains a space you need the brackets, else you get that exact error. The point is not how the variables are declared in VBA, the point is how they're stored in the database.